# .updateOne on MongoDB not working in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following code:

```
connection((db) => {
            db.collection('orders')
                .updateOne(
                    { "_id": req.body._id}, // Filter
                    {"name": req.body.name} // Update
                )
                .then((obj) => {
                    console.log('Updated - ' + obj);
                    res.redirect('orders')
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('Error: ' + err);
                })
        })
```

I want to change the name in the order but it doesn't update it.
The result in the console is

`Updated - {"n":0,"nModified":0,"ok":1}`

I tried to read the documentation but it's horrific

EDIT: `{$set: {"name": req.body.name}},` didn't work as well

EDIT 2: The passed ID matches the _id in the database. Could it be a problem that I'm querying for plain text ID while in the database it is referred to as "ObjectId('5a42ja...')"

Comment: The documentation is fine just always look for the "examples" section: try {
   db.restaurant.updateOne(
      { "name" : "Central Perk Cafe" },
      { $set: { "violations" : 3 } }
   );
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}

Comment: Hmm I'm talking about the documentation related to node.js. I can't write queries like that in there (or can I?)

Comment: can u please share 2 3 mongo documents? Also what will be value of req.body._id?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Maybe you should use "$set" in your update query like this :

```
{$set: {"name": req.body.name}}, // Update
```

More information in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/)

**EDIT**

If it doesn't work, this is probably because there is no match with your filter.

Maybe you should try to match with an ObjectId like this :

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

// In your request
{ "_id": ObjectID(req.body._id)}, // Filter
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe it's because there is no match with your filter ? Can you try to find a document with { "_id": req.body._id} ?

Comment: Hmm the ID passed in req.body._id is the same as the ID in the database, however it is passed as a string, while in the database, it is of type ObjectId(). Could it be that it's not filtering it.because of that?

Answer (score 11):

Use `{$set: {"name": req.body.name}}` (as Sparw mentioned) to update the the properties you want in the document. Also, if the id that you pass as a parameter does not exists in the collection (and you want to create one with the same id) you can pass as a third parameter `{upsert: true}` to create one.

In your example:

```
connection((db) => {
          db.collection('orders')
               .updateOne(
                  { "_id": req.body._id}, // Filter
                  {$set: {"name": req.body.name}}, // Update
                  {upsert: true} // add document with req.body._id if not exists 

             )
            .then((obj) => {
               console.log('Updated - ' + obj);
              res.redirect('orders')
         })
        .catch((err) => {
           console.log('Error: ' + err);
      }) })
```

Comment: I can't understand the logic, but for find and updateOne you should use different syntacsis for search by id. Samples:   -  db.admins.find({ id: req.params.id, isDeleted: false })  and     db.admins.updateOne( { _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id), isDeleted: false}.   Simple question - WHY?

Answer (score 8):

The correct syntax is:

```js
monDb.collection.updateOne(
    {"_id": ObjectId(req.params.id)}, 
    { $set: updateDoc }, 
    function(err, doc) {
      ...
    }
);
```

UPDATE: Not `ObjectID` but `ObjectId`.

Comment: Hey @victor thanks for the answer but would you go more into detail please. It would be useful to know where OP is actually making a mistake in their syntax.

Answer (score 5):

This might happen if the collection schema is missing the field that is to be updated. If the schema is not strict (i.e, isStrict: false), check the update operator. In some cases, the new update value can be same as existing value. In this case, mongoose returns

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Tough @Spraw's answer is right for some cases, but sometimes it doesn't work. I think the convenient answer is `updateOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.body._id)}, {$set: {"name": req.body.name}}, callback)`.

the `_id` in `mongodb` is a `BSON` object and should be instantiated.

Comment: That seemed to be the case for me, it only worked when I added the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have to delete the "_id"/id field before passing the object in the update.

Or it will say that the field is invalid.

Obviously, updated the key while you're using it as a reference isn't the best thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

I had this trouble too, I create a constant with _id from req.body

```
const {_id} = req.body  //pass ID user
await User.updateOne({_id},{$set:data}, (err)=>{
            if(err) return res.status(200).json({
                error: true,
                code: 115,
                message: "Erro to update user!"
            })
        })
```

Comment: You can assign _id directly to updateone method. Like - User.updateOne({req.body._id},{$set:data}

Answer (score -1):

En **NEXT.js**

My project is on React and Next.js. I had this issue.
My silly solution was Restart with (next dev) xD

I added two fields to my Schema model and I tried to update that new fields, but did not works until i restart mi project.

I hope to save time for someone. :)

Answer (score -1):

after spending couple of hours on it I found out that for update I had to convert the id value to Integer, this was however not required where only find was being used

`dbCollection.updateOne({ _id: parseInt(reqBody.id) }`