# Mongoose not update the empty fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've this schema:

```
const collaboratoreschema =new schema({
//_id:schema.Types.ObjectId,
dataregistrazione:{type:Date,default:Date.now,immutable:true},
nominativo:nominativoschema,
localitanascita:{type:String,required:true,trim:true},
provincianascita:{type:String,required:true,trim:true},
datanascita:{type:Date,required:true},
indirizzoresidenza:{type:indirizzoEmbeddedSchema,required:true},
indirizzodomicilio:{type:indirizzoEmbeddedSchema},
telefoni:{type:[telefonoschema],required:true},
indirizziemail:{type:[require('../email.schema.js')],default:undefined},
codicefiscale:{type:String,required:true,uppercase:true,trim:true,match:/^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$/},
note:{type:String,trim:true},
immagine:{type:imageEmbeddedSchema,set:v=>!v || Object.keys(v).length===0?undefined:v},
documenti:{type:[{type:schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'tbFiles'}],set:v=>!v || Object.keys(v).length===0?undefined:v},
datainiziorapporto:{type:Date,required:true},
datafinerapporto:Date,
riferimentoazienda:{type:schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'tbFornitori',set:v=>!v || v==={} || v===''?undefined:v},
attivo:{type:Boolean,default:true},
},{timestamps:true,useNestedStrict: true, omitUndefined:true,collection:'tbCollaboratori'})
```

On save work fine, but on update I've a problem. For example, setting the note field value to empty, when I save the changes with await collaboratore.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:id},employ,{new:true,upsert:true});, do not save the changes, while if I change the value to not empty value, it work fine.
I'd like that the either empty fields and undefined would removed.

**Update**

this is my controller for update:

```
let employ=new collaboratore(); // collaboratore is my model
collaboratoreschema.eachPath(d=>{
    employ[d]=c[d]; //c is collaboratore from req.body
})
await collaboratore.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:id},employ,{new:true,upsert:true});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just tried. It is working fine for me let me know if you are able to reproduce with below script.

6.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
});


run().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

    const UserModel = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
    const newUser = { email: 'test@test.com' };
    const user = new UserModel(newUser);
    const {_id} = await user.save();
    const updatedUser = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id}, {$set: {email: ''}}, {new: true, upsert: true});
    console.log(updatedUser, 'updatedUser')
}
```

Comment: To use $set for every attribute on update doesn't seem comfortable to me.

Comment: similar issue you can read it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656515/updateone-on-mongodb-not-working-in-node-js

Comment: No, it does'nt. I'm thinking to a workaround. To use findOneAndReplace method

Comment: with findOneAndReplace everytime you will have to pass whole object, since it is going to replace your original doc

Comment: Of course, but I'm loosing too much time on this thing